# Найдите лексические ошибки и исправьте их

Tags: лексика

1. Заводу «Комсомолец» предоставлен продолжительный кредит.
2. Именно такой вид деятельности в сфере строительства сегодня самый положительный.
3. Полагаем, что результаты испытаний могут составлять взаимный интерес для наших фирм.
4. Прошу Вас сообщить стоимость 1 шт. кондиционера, необходимую для внедрения в калькуляцию заказчика.
5. Транспортные издержки при перевозках по железной дороге многократно меньше, чем при морских и авиационных.
6. Сейчас эти функции сведены в лице одного технолога.
7. На заводе возникло нестерпимое положение.
   8.Мне было отказано под благоприятным предлогом.
8. Необходимо ещё раз обсчитать все данные.

Answer (score 2):

Заводу «Комсомолец» предоставлен долгосрочный кредит.2. Именно такой вид деятельности в сфере строительства сегодня самый эффективный. 3.Полагаем, что результаты испытаний вызовут  взаимный интерес наших фирм. 4. Прошу Вас сообщить стоимость одного кондиционера, так как эти данные необходимы для внесения в калькуляцию заказчика. 5. Транспортные издержки при железнодорожных перевозках многократно меньше, чем при морских и авиационных. 6.Сейчас эти функции осуществляет один технолог. 7. На заводе возникло нетерпимое положение. 8.Мне было отказано под благовидным предлогом. 9. Необходимо ещё раз просчитать все данные.

Answer (score 2):

1.Заводу «Комсомолец» предоставлен долгосрочный кредит.2. Именно такой вид деятельности в сфере строительства сегодня самый эффективный. 3.Полагаем, что результаты испытаний могут ПРЕДСТАВЛЯТЬ общий интерес наших фирм. 4. Прошу Вас сообщить О стоимости ОДНОЙ ЕДИНИЦЫ ИЗДЕЛИЯ(КОНДИЦИОНЕР), так как эти данные необходимы для внесения в калькуляцию ДЛЯ заказчика. 5. Транспортные издержки при перевозках по железной дороге УСТУПАЮТ морским и авиационным.
 6.Сейчас эти функции ВЫПОЛНЯЕТ один технолог. 7. На заводе возникло нетерпимое  положение. 8.Мне было отказано под благовидным предлогом. 9. Необходимо ещё раз просчитать все данные.

Comment: СООБЩИТЬ можно о чём? и ЧТО? (см. словари).  
5-е предложение у Вас с явной ошибкой. Издержки получились морскими и авиационными))).

Comment: Это не ошибка, это экономический термин:Банк разбил транспортные издержки на морские и сухопутные компоненты. Хотя сухопутные транзитные издержки...Данные исследования включили морские транспортные издержки 97 развивающихся стран, а также дополнительные сухопутные и железнодорожные издержки стран, не имеющих выхода к морю.   http://rudocs.exdat.com/docs/index-181772.html?page=6

Comment: Очень сомневаюсь, что это термин именно экономический - это раз, и два - источник уж очень сомнительный. Во всем Интернете гугл нашел 17 упоминаний "термина". Это все равно что ничего.

Comment: Это 5 задание я помогала делать не раз, однажды студентка принесла работу, исправленную преподавателем, вот он так и исправил, про "одну единицу изделия - тоже оттуда, у них тема была"правильное использование терминов в деловых бумагах", нужно было заменить неверно употреблённые "многократно меньше", "одной штуки кондиционера", "взаимный", "внедрение", "обсчитать". Так что в моих ответах ошибки нет, это проверено

Answer (score 1):

Тут вот какая штука. 
Судя по подборке авторы задания считают, что в каждим из примеров ошибочно одно слово - и всё может быть исправлено заменой на "правильный" синоним. Это не так. Есть термины, которые не имеют прямого общенормативного синонима.

В следующих случаях, имхо, возможно только примерное соответxnвие:

~1. Заводу «Комсомолец» предоставлен кредит на продолжительный срок. 
*"Продолжительный заём" - термин. Не знаю, как насчет кредита.* 
~4. Для внесения в калькуляцию прошу Вас сообщить стоимость одного кондиционера... 
*По большому счету эта фраза не лечится. Как её ни перестраивай, а сочетание "калькуляция заказчика" - это что-то марсианское. Остальное - как мог.*
~5. Транспортные издержки при железнодорожных перевозках во много раз меньше, чем при морских и авиационных.
*Оборот "многократно меньше" считаю косноязычием, несмотря на то, что он все чаще слышится с экранов. Это подтверждается и тем, что подобный вопрос задаётся в интернете не первый раз - и везде есть это "многократно", остальное варьируется. Хорошо бы найти "самый первый" первоисточник.*  
~6.(?)Сейчас эти функции сведены в лице одного технолога. 
*Смысл не ясен, поэтому любая правка сомнительна. Функции сведены одним технологом? Функции осуществляются одним технологом? Функции в лице технолога?*
~9. Необходимо ещё раз просчитать все данные.   
*Этот оборот речи можно признать жаргонным, но правке он не подлежит. "Обсчитать данные" на  профессиональном сленге означает произвести точный подсчет с учетом всех данных. Приставка "об" имеет здесь тот же смысл, что и в "обернуть", "обклеить", даже "обсудить". "Просчитать" или подобные не несут нужного смысла.*
//---
Обсчитать
...
2. что. Спец.
Произвести подсчёт чего-л., просчитать что-л. О. все параметры. О. все варианты. < Обсчитывать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Обсчитываться, -ается; страд. Обсчитывание, -я; ср. (1 зн.).
БТС, Кузнецов.
(хотя даже тут определение не до конца точное)